# Keras MultiGPU training fails with error message, "IndexError: pop from empty list"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, multi-gpu

I want to take advantage of multiple GPUs in training my Keras/Tensorflow model with the `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()` method.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
# Imports
import tensorflow as tf
import model # Module of functions for building the model

# Check GPU availability
devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print('Num GPUs:', len(devices))
print(devices)

# Prepare dataset (Xtrain/Xtest are Numpy arrays with shape, (None, 600, 23))
Xtrain, Xtest = models.get_dataset() 

# Datasets as tf.data.dataset objects
batch_size = 256
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((Xtrain, Xtrain)).batch(batch_size)
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((Xtest, Xtest)).batch(batch_size)

# Build model for synchronous multi-GPU training
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print('Number of devices in strategy: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))

with strategy.scope():
    # Define model hyperparameters                                                                                                              
    input_dim = Xtrain.shape[1:]
    clipnorm = 100
    learning_rate = 1e-4
    latent_dim = 50
    dropout = 0.33

    # Compile model                                                                                                                       
    encoder = models.Encoder(input_dim=input_dim, latent_dim=latent_dim,
                             dropout=dropout)
    decoder = models.Decoder(input_dim=input_dim, latent_dim=latent_dim,
                             dropout=dropout)
    m1vae = models.ProtVAE(encoder=encoder, decoder=decoder, name='m1vae')
    m1vae.compileVAE(input_dim=input_dim, latent_dim=latent_dim,
                     learning_rate=learning_rate, clipnorm=clipnorm)
```

When I run the code, if fails in the compilation step with the following error message:

```
Num GPUs: 2

[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:1', device_type='GPU')]

Number of devices in strategy: 2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "work_python_scripts/test_m1vae_gpu.py", line 114, in <module>
    m1vae.compileVAE(input_dim=input_dim, latent_dim=latent_dim, learning_rate=learning_rate,
  File "/home/jgado/condaenvs/tfgpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 332, in __ex\
it__
    _pop_per_thread_mode()
  File "/home/jgado/condaenvs/tfgpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribution_strategy_context.py", li\
ne 65, in _pop_per_thread_mode
    ops.get_default_graph()._distribution_strategy_stack.pop(-1)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

I wonder if this is because my functions (`Encoder`, `Decoder`, `ProtVAE`, and `CompileVAE`) are defined in a separate module (`models.py`). But I feel this shouldn't be a problem since these functions are called within the strategy.scope() block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check in your module (models.py).
Comment out all the clear session function. For ex, `K.clear_session()`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Could you explain why clearing the session causes the MirroredStrategy to fail? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, to my knowledge I do not have any such method in my code, but I am still consistently facing this error. Do you have any other insight in it?

Comment: I've no idea why this works but it does... Check your model definitions if you are using an external library for instance here;

import model # Module of functions for building the model.

They often contain a clear_session() near the top.